# How to write different values to multiple output files in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, fileoutputstream, bufferedwriter

I have the following Java 8 code that creates 1 file fine (the content in the file is a singular line of text). What's the best way to change this code so I end up with three separate text files?

```
String os = System.getProperty("os.name");
String jv = System.getProperty("java.version");
String userfolder = System.getProperty("user.home");

try (Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                new FileOutputStream(userfolder + "opsys.txt"), "utf-8")))
                {
                 writer.write((String) os);
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) 
                {
                e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
                {
                e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) 
                {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

**Output I'm trying to achieve:**

- 3 text files

  - named opsys.txt, version.txt and userhome.txt.
  - Each file contains the relevant System.getProperty answer.

Comment: Take the Writer code to a function that accepts 2 params, the String you want to save and the fileName.

Comment: @Dez, I appreciate the reply and although to some may seem straight forward - it means I can now move forward with my learning! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can put all the functionality for write files in a separate method, something like:

```
private void writeFile(String fileName, String content) {

    try (Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
            new FileOutputStream(fileName), "utf-8")))
    {
        writer.write((String) content);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

After that, your previous code becomes something like:

```
String os = System.getProperty("os.name");
String jv = System.getProperty("java.version");
String userfolder = System.getProperty("user.home");

//Here you call the writeFile method the number of time that you need:
writeFile(userfolder + "opsys.txt", os);
....
```

With this approach you can create any  files that you need.

Comment: Just to confirm - this is working for me. Thanks again Manuel!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple method as shown below which takes fileName and environment variable name as input arguments:

```
public void createAndWriteFile(String fileNmae, String envName) {
        String content = System.getProperty(envName);
        String userfolder = System.getProperty("user.home");
        try (Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                        new FileOutputStream(userfolder + fileNmae), "utf-8"))) {
         writer.write(content);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
```

Now, call the above method 3 times as shown below:

```
String os = System.getProperty("os.name");
createAndWriteFile("opsys.txt",os);
String javaVersion = System.getProperty("java.version");
createAndWriteFile("version.txt",javaVersion);
String userHome = System.getProperty("user.home");
createAndWriteFile("userhome.txt",userHome);
```